# Does the following Java program must print "num:1 m_i:2 " because of synchronization order

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I just want to check if my understanding of the JMM's thread start synchronization rule is correct:

Does the following Java program must print "num:1 m_i:2 " just because of  the following synchronization order.

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4

---

### An action that starts a thread synchronizes-with the first action in the thread it starts.

```
public class ThreadHappenBefore {
    static int num;
    int m_i;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ThreadHappenBefore hb = new ThreadHappenBefore();
        num = 1;
            hb.m_i = 2;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("num:"+num);
                System.out.println("m_i:"+hb.m_i);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @irreputable , just to make sure it have nothing to do with final or static.  Does the rule means:  hb(num = 1, hb.m_i = 2) ,  hb( hb.m_i = 2, thread start) , hb( thread start, read num)  , hb( read num,read m_i) in this program?

Comment: thanks,more confident on this now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything coded *before* other code is guaranteed to *happen before* the other code in a given thread **when the earlier code has an effect on the later code**. Because the thread start is coded *after* the assignments, **and the assignments *affect* the outcome of the print statements**, these assignments are "visible" (ie happened before) the the code that prints them.

**However, there is no such guarantee made to the effects of order of execution when viewed from another thread.**

**EDITED** (thanks to commenters)

Added a refinement (in bold) to the above regarding reordering.

Comment: In addition, there is a crucial 'happens before' between the `start()` call in the main thread and the call to the `run()` method in the new thread.

Comment: Nope. The VM is allowed to reorder instructions as it likes as long as the behavior is identical for the own thread. The reason why this works here is because the creation of a thread (the start() not the new Thread()) ensures a happens-before relationship. If that was not the case (ie creation of a thread does not ensure a memory barrier), it'd be perfectly fine to get two 0s here.

Comment: @Steven_C and @Voo - I have refined my answer to factor in both your comments

Answer (score 0):

*What* 'synchronization order'? There is no synchronization here. This is just normal excecution order. All the assignments occur before the thread even starts. I don't know why this is considered mysterious.

Comment: synchronization order is defined by JMM, see http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4

Comment: @Ben Xu there being only one thread until both values have been written, I don't see how any of that applies. All you are dealing with here is single-threaded execution order.

Comment: @EJP: If thread creation didn't create a hb relationship, it would be perfectly correct for the example to print 0,0 - I don't see how this is NOT important here.

Comment: @Voo not at all. The values have all been assigned before the the thread even starts, so there is only one prior state to order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think u have a synchronize issue here
you will have the result u expect because of the code order.
synchronize issue can occur if you have several threads referring to same source

Answer (score 0):

Since so far nobody except Stephen C in a comment has posted the correct answer: The creation of a thread (the start() not the new Thread()!) ensures a happens-before relationship.

If this was not the case, the JVM could easily reorder the instructions as long as it can guarantee that the own thread wouldn't see a difference.

You can be pretty sure that in every language with a sensible multithreaded memory model that there will be some memory barrier for this case, because otherwise you couldn't reliably pass parameters to a thread.

Answer (score 0):

No, it prints the right thing because of the "happens-before" relation in section [17.4.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5). If you look at the discussion below the section, it is also clearly stated:

> A call to start() on a thread happens-before any actions in the
>   started thread.

and furthermore:

> If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in
>   program order, then hb(x, y).

Therefore the two assignments are guaranteed to have happened before the read in the thread.

You have no synchronization in your example.